# xmlrpc.php not found or unable to stat [Ubuntu 14.04 Server]

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I just setup a new Ubuntu server with a LAMP stack. I'm using it only for some React.JS development, and has no domain name associated to it. I'm finding that my error log is riddled with this error:

```
[Mon Apr 18 15:59:18.045904 2016] [:error] [pid 24059] [client 188.241.234.58:50084] script '/home/pinetar/public_html/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I understand the error that the file doesn't exist, and from what I can tell its probably just bots looking for an exploit. My concern is the error log getting out of hand and wasting server resources.

Is there a way to block requests for this file or is there a downside to doing so? My server isn't very powerful (512MB) since it's just for development and testing..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be concerned about logging overhead or log file size. If the log file size grows out of hand you can [`logrotate(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/logrotate.8.html) it and compress old logs in the process. Text files with many similar entries tend to be very well compressible.

You could even set up your custom cron job to filter those entries out of the rotated log files.